# Rails define controller as root controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I know that in Rails (3.2.2), I can route requests to `/` with the following in routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'main_pages#index'
```

How can I make MainPages the default controller for all index actions?

For example, if I used `rails g controller` to make a new controller called "Foo" with actions "hi" and "bye", Rails would automatically route `myapp/foo/hi` and `myapp/foo/bye`.

How can I make MainPages the default controller for index actions, so if I make a method in MainPages called "about", Rails will route `/about`?

## Edit

Then, once I've routed that, should I link to these new pages with `link_to` or just use a direct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One default Rails route is :

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

You could override it with your controller name :

```
match '/:action(/:id)', :controller => 'main_pages'
```

Comment: link_to works the same as ever, it'll take into account your routes. Or should, try it.  link_to remains the same as what you were doing before link_to(:controller => "main", ...), or link_to(main_index_path) or whatever you were doing before.